# $.data returning randomly returning undefined in Chrome. Rails App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I'm having a serious issue that I cannot figure out.  For some reason calling $.data is randomly deciding to return false in Chrome.  Seems to work fine in FireFox and Safari.  I can't find any pattern and nothing seems to be off with the data coming in from the backend, and all the data to create the JS object is coming in fine, but creating the object will fail.  Any help would be SUPER appreciated!! Thank you!!

```js
$j('#search_results div.actor .placeholder img').click(function(obj){
  if(obj.target.tagName.toUpperCase()=="A" || $j(obj.target).parents('A').length>0){return true;}

  var actor=$j(this);
  if(!actor.hasClass('actor')){
    actor = actor.parents('.actor');
  }

  var data=$j.data(actor.get(0), 'data');
```

$(actor).get(0) returns an object containing data on said actor.

```html
<div id="actor_3484" class="actor already_submitted selected multiple_headshots" href="/p/3484/x0bugnxb2jl43mj4jpvd204muijvr6" actor_id="3484" search_text="
     
           
             

           

            
           

           
             

  .fa {
    margin-left: 17.5px;
    background: #dfdfdf;
    color: #6d6d6d;
    max-width: 20px;
    min-width: 20px;
    max-height: 15px;
    min-height: 15px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #b7b6b6;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #9a9999;
    font-size: 11.5px;
  }

  .actor_actions .fa:hover, .search_results_actions_left .fa:hover {
    background: #396daa;
    color: white;
  }

  .fa-file-text-o:hover {background: #dfdfdf!important; color: #6d6d6d!important;}

  .favorite_actor:hover, .favorited {background: #18c4a3!important; color: white!important;}


  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .actor_actions {
    left: 117.5px!important;
  }

  .actor-selector-bg {
    margin-left: 17.5px!important;
    max-width: 20px!important;
    min-width: 20px!important;
    border: 1px solid #c1c0c0;
    background: #dfdfdf!important;
  }

  .actor-selector {
    margin-left: 1px!important;
  }

  .fa-user {
    color: white!important;
    font-size:10px;
    margin-top: -2px;
  }

  .premium_plus, .premium_plus:hover {background-color: #fbb03a!important; color: white;}
  .premium, .premium:hover {background-color: #3c86b6!important; color: white;}
  .basic, .basic:hover {background-color: #828e97!important;}

  .r_n_p {
    background: #396daa!important;
    color: white!important;
  }

  .fa-usd:hover {background: #ad1f1f!important; color: white!important;}
  .overscale {background: #ad1f1f!important; color: white!important;}

  .black, .black:hover {background-color: black!important; color: white!important;}
  .blue, .blue:hover {background-color: #396daa!important; color: white!important;}
  .green, .green:hover {background-color: #35ac48!important; color: white!important;}
  .red, .red:hover {background-color: #ac364f!important; color: white!important;}
  .dark_gray {color: #6d6d6d;}

  .gray_cam {
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: default;
  }
  .gray_cam:hover {
    background-color: #dfdfdf!important;
    color: gray!important;
  }

  .fa-upload:hover {
    background-color: #65bf92!important;
    color: white!important;
  }

  .has_sub_vid {
    background-color: #65bf92;
    color: white!important;
  }
  .has_sub_vid:hover {
    background-color: #65bf92!important;
  }

  .repd {
    background: #ac364f;
    color: white;
  }

  .info_btn {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .i {
    position: absolute;
    margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;
  }



i
  E
P

  


  
    N
  

  
    
  


  



    
      
      
    



  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($(&quot;.info_link_actor_3484&quot;), function(i,v){
      $(v).attr('href', &quot;/agent_account/search/actor_update_stats?id=3484&amp;search[f_project_id]=6380&amp;amp;role_id=17461&quot;)
    });
  });




           
           
         


         
           
  .fa {
    display: block;
  }
  .search_results_actions_left {
    margin-left: -3px;
  }

  .bookout_button:hover {background: #ad1f1f!important; color: white!important;}

  .actor_booked {background: #ad1f1f!important; color: white!important;}
  .red_text {color: #ac364f;}








  F


  

    M


    U

    
      B


  
    
    
  

         
         
             
  Abbott, Felicita



  NU
  
    6' 155lbs
    ON HOLD
  
  


    
      Already submitted for:
      Jenny
    








         
       ">
     <div class="placeholder ">
           <div class="polaroid_holder">
             <img class="actor_headshot" actor_id="3484" headshot_id="2106822" src="http://localhost:3000/images/headshot_pending_generic.jpg" width="121" original_ratio="1.4" height="170">

           </div>

            <div class="actor_update_stats" id="actor_update_stats_3484" style="display:none;">
           </div>

           <div id="" class="actor_actions search_results_actions_left ">
             <style>

  .fa {
    margin-left: 17.5px;
    background: #dfdfdf;
    color: #6d6d6d;
    max-width: 20px;
    min-width: 20px;
    max-height: 15px;
    min-height: 15px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #b7b6b6;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #9a9999;
    font-size: 11.5px;
  }

  .actor_actions .fa:hover, .search_results_actions_left .fa:hover {
    background: #396daa;
    color: white;
  }

  .fa-file-text-o:hover {background: #dfdfdf!important; color: #6d6d6d!important;}

  .favorite_actor:hover, .favorited {background: #18c4a3!important; color: white!important;}


  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .actor_actions {
    left: 117.5px!important;
  }

  .actor-selector-bg {
    margin-left: 17.5px!important;
    max-width: 20px!important;
    min-width: 20px!important;
    border: 1px solid #c1c0c0;
    background: #dfdfdf!important;
  }

  .actor-selector {
    margin-left: 1px!important;
  }

  .fa-user {
    color: white!important;
    font-size:10px;
    margin-top: -2px;
  }

  .premium_plus, .premium_plus:hover {background-color: #fbb03a!important; color: white;}
  .premium, .premium:hover {background-color: #3c86b6!important; color: white;}
  .basic, .basic:hover {background-color: #828e97!important;}

  .r_n_p {
    background: #396daa!important;
    color: white!important;
  }

  .fa-usd:hover {background: #ad1f1f!important; color: white!important;}
  .overscale {background: #ad1f1f!important; color: white!important;}

  .black, .black:hover {background-color: black!important; color: white!important;}
  .blue, .blue:hover {background-color: #396daa!important; color: white!important;}
  .green, .green:hover {background-color: #35ac48!important; color: white!important;}
  .red, .red:hover {background-color: #ac364f!important; color: white!important;}
  .dark_gray {color: #6d6d6d;}

  .gray_cam {
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: default;
  }
  .gray_cam:hover {
    background-color: #dfdfdf!important;
    color: gray!important;
  }

  .fa-upload:hover {
    background-color: #65bf92!important;
    color: white!important;
  }

  .has_sub_vid {
    background-color: #65bf92;
    color: white!important;
  }
  .has_sub_vid:hover {
    background-color: #65bf92!important;
  }

  .repd {
    background: #ac364f;
    color: white;
  }

  .info_btn {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .i {
    position: absolute;
    margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;
  }

</style>

<a href="/agent_account/search/actor_update_stats?id=3484&amp;search[f_project_id]=6380&amp;amp;role_id=17461" class="fancybox info_link info_link_actor_3484"><i class="fa letters info_btn"><span class="i">i</span></i></a>
  <a href="/agent_account/edit_actor/3484" target="_blank"><i class="fa letters" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 11px;">E</i></a>
<a href="javascript: (function(){window.open('/p/3484/x0bugnxb2jl43mj4jpvd204muijvr6', 'actor_popup_window','height=870,width=1200,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,status=0')})();"><i class="fa letters" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 11px;">P</i></a>

  <a href="/agent_account/actors/3484/email_profile_form?height=275&amp;width=650" class="fancybox"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>


  <a href="/agent_account/submissions/288574/actors/3484/note?width=350&amp;height=200&amp;fancybox=1" always_hover="note" class="note fancybox">
    <i class="fa letters right_note " aria-hidden="true">N</i>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="overscale flip_attribute" always_hover="overscale">
    <i class="fa fa-usd previously_overscale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>


  <!-- <a href="#" title="Click here to mark this actor as a special selection. You can only have ten special selections." class="special flip_attribute" always_hover="special"><img src="/images/layout/search/special.png"></a> -->



    <a href="/agent_account/submissions/288574/actors/3484/headshots?width=650&amp;height=450&amp;role_id=17461" class="thickbox " always_hover="multiple_headshots">
      <!-- <img class="autohover more_pictures disabled_action" src="/images/layout/search/more_pictures.png" alt="More pictures" /> -->
      <i class="fa fa-camera-retro" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($(".info_link_actor_3484"), function(i,v){
      $(v).attr('href', "/agent_account/search/actor_update_stats?id=3484&search[f_project_id]=6380&amp;role_id=17461")
    });
  });
</script>



           </div>
           <br clear="all">
         </div>


         <div class="search_results_actions_left ">
           <style>
  .fa {
    display: block;
  }
  .search_results_actions_left {
    margin-left: -3px;
  }

  .bookout_button:hover {background: #ad1f1f!important; color: white!important;}

  .actor_booked {background: #ad1f1f!important; color: white!important;}
  .red_text {color: #ac364f;}

</style>






  <a href="http://localhost:3000/agent_account/actors/3484/favorites?width=400&amp;height=220&amp;agent_id=392" class="fancybox"><i class="fa letters favorite_actor " aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 11px;">F</i></a>


  <a href="mailto:lolita.heathcote@lemke.biz"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

    <a href="/agent_account/submissions/288574/actors/3484/edit?height=170&amp;width=355&amp;refresh=false" class="change_role fancybox"><i class="fa letters" aria-hidden="true">M</i></a>


    <a id="unsubmit_3484" onclick="unsubmit('/agent_account/submissions/unsubmit.288574', 392, 1978392, 3484, 288574, 17461); return false;" href="#"><i class="fa letters" aria-hidden="true">U</i></a>

    <a href="/agent_account/submissions/288574/actors/3484/book_outs?width=350&amp;height=200" class="books_out fancybox">
      <i class="fa letters bookout_button " aria-hidden="true">B</i>
</a>

  <a href="/agent_account/actor_agent_relationships/3484/edit?height=275&amp;width=650" class="fancybox edit_note">
    <!-- <img src="/images/layout/search/privatenote_gray.png" alt="Privatenote gray" /> -->
    <i class="fa fa-file-text-o " aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>

         </div>
         <div class="search_results_info">
             <p style="font-size:15px;">
  Abbott, Felicita
</p>

<p>
  <small><span class="dark_gray" title="Non-union">NU</span></small>
  </p><p class="dark_gray">
    6' 155lbs
    </p><div class="red_text">ON HOLD</div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
<p></p>

    <p style="color:red;">
      Already submitted for:<br>
      <a class="thickbox" href="http://localhost:3000/agent_account/projects/6380/roles/17465/popup_info?KeepThis=true">Jenny</a>
    </p>








         </div>
       </div>
```

Thank you again!

Comment: Why not replace `var data=$j.data(actor.get(0), 'data');` with just `actor.data('data');` since `actor` is already a jQuery object?

Comment: Sadly that's still returning undefined

Comment: It was just a suggestion to make the code a bit cleaner. Without knowing how the `data` property is populated, there's no way of knowing what might be failing.